# Troubleshooting DLL function call from Excel Vba

Tags: vba, excel, dllimport

I'm trying to call a function from a DLL from VBA in Excel.

My Excel VBA macro looks like this:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function TestFunction1 Lib "mylib.dll" (ByVal k As Double) As Double

Public Function TestDll(k As Double) As Double
    Debug.Print ("Start")

    Dim r As Double
    r = TestFunction1(k)

    Debug.Print ("Got result of " + r)
    Debug.Print ("Done")

    TestDll = r
End Function
```

Now when I call it from an Excel cell with something like "=TestDll(3.0)", it doesn't work. I see the "Start" string in the immediate window, but nothing else. It's like an error is happening exactly when "TestFunction1" is being called. Excel displays "#VALUE!" in the cell.

I can also set a breakpoint in the debugger, but when I get to the TestFunction1 call, it just ends. There is no sort of error message I can find.

My question is, how do I debug this? I'm not getting any error message. It simply doesn't work. How can I figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: You are never assigning a value to `r`.  And you are never declaring `ret` as Double.  (Not sure whether those are causing your issues, but I suggest you fix them anyway.)

Comment: You can try adding the .dll file to the VBA project references and F2 to search for the method in the Object Explorer. Another thing that you can try is to use `As Object` instead of `As Double`. I don't think we can help you much without any information about `mylib.dll` and `TestFunction1`

Comment: @YowE3K Sorry, I confused `r` with `ret`. They should have been the same. Fixed it.

Comment: This is a well-phrased question, but without the DLL and TestFunction1, it is not really something that anyone is likely able to assist with, beyond very high-level advice. Otherwise, the question's scope is limited to a very unique problem (i.e., limited to your specific DLL & function) and may not be very useful for the rest of SO community.

Comment: @Slai When I tried to add the file as you say, I get the error message "Can't add a reference to the specified file".

Comment: @carrie88 yes, I was expecting that. My guess is that the declaration of the function does not match the underlying types. Where did you get that declaration from ? `PtrSafe` is for 64 bit office? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831

Comment: @DavidZemens My question isn't "please fix this." My question is specifically "how do I debug this thing?" How do I get Excel VBA to give me an error message or tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I gave you the code to trap the error. :)

Comment: Figure it out by looking at the c++ function's definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable which you are using in debug statement,has an error and hence the UDF fails.
 Rest is fine.  Actually you need to convert `r` to string or use `&` for   concatenation in your debug statement.

Edit: to include error handler.

```
Public Function TestDll(k As Double) As Double
    Debug.Print ("Start")

    Dim r       As Double

    '/ Add a error handler
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    '/ Assuming that your testfunction will return 10*parameter
    r = k * 10


    '/ The variable which you are returning,has a error and hence the UDF fails.
    '/ Rest is fine. Here you will get type mismatch error.
    Debug.Print ("Got result of " + r)

    '/ Actually you need to convert it to string or use `&` for concatenation
    Debug.Print ("Got result of " + CStr(r))

    '/ or
    Debug.Print ("Got result of " & r)


    Debug.Print ("Done")

    TestDll = r

errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        '/ Error trapped and you get actual error desc and number.
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: THis is good advice regarding the `&` vs `+` for concatenation, the latter will yield a Type Mismatch error in this case. However, the root of the problem seems to be with the call to TestFunction1: *when I get to the TestFunction1 call, it just ends*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run in the debugger, execution doesn't go past " r = TestFunction1(k)".

Comment: see the edit to my answer. It will help you to trap the actual error. Post the error message and error number. May be some one could be able to help.

Comment: @teddy2 The "On Error" part is exactly what I needed! I have an actual error message to go on now, and hopefully I can get it from here. Thanks x1000! (I'd upvote you, but apparently I can't?)

Comment: great. dont worry about upvotes. As long as it works for you I am happy. :)